# How to remove a only div tag in another div

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a many div tags with class comment_content.How can I remove div tags in that div tags without content? This is what I tried so far:

```
$documentText = preg_replace ('<div class="comment_content">/<div>.*<\/div>/<\/div>|si',"", $documentText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first div without the / and the last with escaped / should work, also the .* is not nessesary and you need the g operator

```
$documentText = preg_replace('/(<div class="comment_content">)<div><\/div>(<\/div>)/mig',"$1$2", $documentText);
```

This should work.

Comment: But  like this will be removed all div tags not only that which in  comment_content  div

Comment: `/g` is not a valid modifier in PHP's regex implementation (PCRE). That's Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it will remove your div tags but not its content:

```
preg_replace("/<div class='comment_content'>(.*?)<\/div>/", "$1", $s);
```

Comment: I want to remove that div tags which in the <div class='comment_content'>